# PhotosPicker in SwiftUI showing camera images upside down

Tags: swiftui

Pictures from camera gallery are showing upside down. What would be the problem please? i have tried multiple frames and even removed the frame and they still load upside down. You can experience that with the default "flower" image in the simulator. Also the navigation title not showing up in the sim and phone but showing up in Preview, any help is much appreciated...

App running on my phone: [image]

Code is bellow ;

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct CreateListing: View {
    
    @Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var pickerItems = [PhotosPickerItem]()
    @State private var selectedImages = [Image]()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Photos")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        PhotosPicker(selection: $pickerItems, maxSelectionCount: 20, selectionBehavior: .ordered, matching: .images) {
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 30)
                                .foregroundStyle(.green.gradient)
                                .overlay {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ScrollView (.horizontal) {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0..<selectedImages.count, id: \.self) { i in
                                selectedImages[i]
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                    .contentMargins(5, for: .scrollContent)
                    
                    
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding(.top)
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .onChange(of: pickerItems) {
                    Task {
                        selectedImages.removeAll()
                        
                        for item in pickerItems {
                            if let loadedImage = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Image.self) {
                                selectedImages.append(loadedImage)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Listing summary")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        CreateListing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud. I have tried the app on my older phone iphone XR and it works correctly with my original code but behaves strange on iphone 14 pro. Yeah might be a bug and thank you for your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange behaviour, probably a bug. You could try this workaround,
using an intermediate `UIImage`, works for me:

```
Task {
     selectedImages.removeAll()
     for item in pickerItems {
         if let loadedImage = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self),
            let uimg = UIImage(data: loadedImage) {
             selectedImages.append(Image(uiImage: uimg))
         }
     }
 }
```